# Cannot store an array of classes

Tags: c#, class, types

I am trying to store an array of classes which I can initialise later on. I am trying to do it like so:

```
Type[] x = { className };
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> 'myNamespace.className' is a 'type' but it is used like a 'variable'

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [**`typeof`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator, which is used to obtain a `System.Type`for a type.

```
Type[] x = { typeof(className) };
```

EDIT:

In response to your comment: to create an instance of the type from a `System.Type`, use an appropriate overload of the [**`Activator.CreateInstance`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) method.

E.g.

```
Type t = typeof(int);

// Boxed Int32 with value 0
object o = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

In your case, since you know the base-type of the class, you can of course cast the return-value to the base-type.

Comment: That seems to work! Another quick thing: how would I go about initialising it (I know the parent class)?